# Magento 2 and VES theme. Site front and back shows corrupt? PHP version issue?

Tags: magento2

I have installed via Quick install a VES Magento 2 free theme. I had to set PHP to version 7.0, 7.1 doesn't work. When I opened first time the site after installation it looked OK but on the second time (no changes are done) it collaps. pls have a look at iamyorda.com. I believe it might have to do with the index file and how it set its page. See below the index.page. Hopefully, you see the error immediately. Thx for the support!

> 

try {
    require **DIR** . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<


    
        
        Autoload error

{$e->getMessage()}

HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);

> 

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to run

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

it is better to run following command after deploying static content

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Best Regards,
Krunal Pathak

Answer (score 0):

For magento2 you must have the SSH Access, unless you can't able to maintain / run the magento website in server. kindly ask your server provider for a **SSH Access**.

you must should also set the default cron jobs for magento. After all are done. kindly run the below comamnd in ssh

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

After that,

```
php bin/magento cache:clean;

php bin/magento indexer:reindex;

php bin/magento cache:flush;
```